# Not Able to Establish Database Connection from PowerBI Web to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, virtual-machine, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

For the PowerBI Desktop version I am able to do the refresh. But when I publish it then in the PowerBI we I am not able to configure schedule refresh as it says that -

```
Failed to update data source credentials: An error happened while reading data from the provider: 'No such host is known'Hide details
Activity ID:    7884d0c3-e2f2-441f-b991-27785b7a5e25
Request ID: d2b18b4b-8074-1832-0c47-76a9267543e8
Status code:    400
Time:   Fri Feb 23 2024 15:55:17 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Service version:    13.0.22683.73
```

The PostgreSQL is hosted in the virtual machine. We also tried to configure and enable all connection.

Long story short with PowerBI desktop it is working but with PowerBI Web App it is not.

[image]

Comment: Tell me, is the Power BI Desktop also installed on the VM, or is it on your main computer from where you are accessing your PBI Web? The basic cause could be that the 'username' and the 'password' are different. Also, is the 'postgres' access channeled through the 'web app' VM? For accessing the 'DB' VM, the architecture and ports are configured to be accessed through the 'web app' VM, and usernames and passwords of all should be the same.

Comment: No, the powerbi Desktop is not in the VM. It is in my main computer.
I am able to access the db from PgAdmin from my main computer.
Tried giving the below to the config file
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5